# Discord bot to assign role to users tagged in a message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Not getting a response from the bot at all but the console displays the msg Hi! You're logged in as: botNameHere!

```
bot.once('ready', () => {
    console.info(`Hi! You're logged in as: ${bot.user.tag}!`) 
})

bot.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
    const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'assignrole') {
      // Check if the message mentions a user
      if (message.mentions.users.size === 1) {
        // Get the user object
        const user = message.mentions.users.first();
        // Get the role by name
        const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name === 'Group 1');

        // Assign the role to the user
        if (role) {
          const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
          member.roles.add(role)
            .then(() => {
              message.reply(`Role ${role.name} assigned to ${user.tag}`);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);
              message.reply('There was an error assigning the role.');
            });
        } else {
          message.reply('Role not found.');
        }
      } else {
        message.reply('Please mention a user.');
      }
    }
  }
});

bot.login(TOKEN);
```

Expecting it to assign the role listed above to the user that is tagged in the Discord Message

Comment: can you show your `bot` definition and which `discord.js` version are you using?

Comment: can you show us the version of your `discord.js` ?

Comment: latest version 

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages
  ]
});